# What does -g option do in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I see many tutorials on gdb asking to use -g option while compiling c program. I fail to understand what does the -g option actually do.

Comment: Debug Information is produced for debugging the software... You should google it yourself, if you don't know. This is not a question worth asking (imho). I didn't read this, but maybe it will be helpful for you: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/

Comment: True. It seems like i didn't put enough consideration behind my statement,  I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes the compiler add debug information to the resulting binaries. This information allows a debugger to associate the instructions in the code with source code files and line numbers. Having debug symbols makes certain kinds of debugging (like stepping through code) much easier, if not possible at all.

The `-g` option actually has a few tunable parameters, check the manual. Also, it's most useful if you don't optimize the code, so use `-O0` or `-Og` (in newer versions) - optimizations break the connection between instructions and source code. (Most importantly you have to *not* omit frame pointers from function calls, which is a popular optimization but basically completely ruins the ability to walk up the call stack.)

The debug symbols themselves are written in  a standardized language (I think it's DWARF2), and there are libraries for reading that. A program could even read its own debug symbols at runtime, for instance.

Debug symbols (as well as other kinds of symbols like function names) can be removed from a binary later on with the `strip` command. However, since you'll usually combine debug symbols with unoptimizied builds, there's not much point in that - rather, you'd build a release binary with different optimizations *and* without symbols from the start.

Other compilers such as MSVC don't include debug information in the binary itself, but rather store it in a separate file and/or a "symbol server" -- so if the home user's application crashes and you get the core dump, you can pull up the symbols from your server and get a readable stack trace. GCC might add a feature like that in the future; I've seen some discussions about it.

Comment: "Most importantly you have to not omit frame pointers from function calls, which is a popular optimization but basically completely ruins the ability to walk up the call stack." -- this part of your answer is incorrect -- GCC (since version 4.6) emits correct unwind info, and GDB has no trouble walking up the call stack in such code.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Interesting, thanks - is the unwind info only included with `-g`?

Comment: "is the unwind info only included with -g?" No: on x86_64 it has been included since forever (you can't unwind without it). On ix86, it is now also always included (unless explicitly suppressed with `-fno-unwind-tables`).